# Change owncloud data directory to an external drive

Tags: permissions, ntfs, raspberry-pi, ntfs-3g, owncloud

Owncloud 5.0.9 is installed on my raspberry pi and is working flawlessly. But since my raspberry pi hasn't much space, I wanted to move the data directory on an external drive.

I have a 1,5GB external drive formatted in NTFS mounted on `/home/pi/media` and the new data directory is `/home/pi/media/owncloud/data/`

The `/etc/fstab/` looks like this:

```
UUID=xxxxxxxxx   /home/pi/media    ntfs-3g     defaults      0       0
```

It doesn't work if I set the permissions on the ntfs drive with

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/pi/media/owncloud/data
```

The browser is giving this error if I go to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/owncloud/:

```
Data directory (/home/pi/media/owncloud/data) is readable for other users
Please change the permissions to 0770 so that the directory cannot be listed by other users.
```

How do I set the permissions right?
Also MiniDLNA is configured to use this drive, so it should not interrupt each other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it myself!

By default you are not able to set permissions on NTFS formatted drives, but with NTFS-3G you can. Just enable it on mount.

1. Add `permissions` to the options in `/etc/fstab/`. It should look like this:

```
UUID=xxxxxxxxx   /home/pi/media    ntfs-3g     defaults,permissions      0       0
```

2. Reboot your Raspberry Pi so that the drive get mounted with permissions.

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

3. Now you are able to set permissions. For owncloud like this:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/pi/media/owncloud/data
```